# Get all elements in an array after a certain index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

In python doing this would be as simple as:

```
mylist = ['red','blue','green','yellow']
print(mylist[1:])
'blue','green','yellow'
```

When I tried this in JavaScript mylist[0] returned 'red' etc. but when I tried doing something like mylist[1:] in JavaScript it was not correct syntax.

What is a good method of doing this in JavaScript? Basically get all elements after a specified index, and to be specific, I am doing this in Node.js, but I do not think that matters much.

Comment: Just an extra thought about your code, make sure you use the var keyword unless you specifically need to implicitly declare it. It would also be good to use camelCase for "mylist" so it would be `myList`. That is preferred by many people.

Comment: this is just an example

Comment: You're saying "get all elements"... what do you mean by "get"? Make a new array from them? Use the values for something?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `slice` method like below:

```
mylist = ['red','blue','green','yellow'];
console.log(mylist.slice(1));
```

**Output:**

```
["blue", "green", "yellow"]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rf0s3cqd/) | [Array slice method - MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: @m59, I don't know python as well as I know JS, but doesn't `mylist[1:]` return a new list in the same way that `mylist.slice(1)` returns a new array?

Comment: @zzzzBov Hmm, perhaps you are right!. There's nothing in the original post to suggest that it is actual an array being printed, rather than a comma separated list of the array's values. Hard to say.

Comment: .slice(1) would only return blue

Comment: @riyoken no it doesn't. It returns a new array starting at that point. I believe you use `splice()` instead of `slice()`

Comment: i would need it to return all of the elements in a new array after and including the 1

Comment: @riyoken: No mate, it returns all from 1 to end. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfVzg/)